# Do cap_setfcap capability can be used to grant full capabilities to an exe file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, capabilities

I have a file (let's call it prog) that has the cap_setfcap capabiility.
Can I use it to grant prog (the file itself) full capabilities?
I know it's not recommended, I just want to know if it can be done.

EDIT:
To clarify: I want to grant prog ALL the capabilities that the system has (all sets).
I get it that the file can grant himself full "file capabilities", the question is can he grant himself full "run-time capabilities" as well?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You probably have to clarify your question, as there are many sets of capabilities, and it is not clear, in which set you have `CAP_SETFCAP` for the file and what do you mean exactly by "granting prog full capabilities" - do you mean run-time capabilities or file capabilities? Which set?

Comment: Anyway, AFAIR, you cannot guarantee that this program will have the full effective capability set in the runtime, as this may be limited by dropping some caps from the bounding set (e.g. `systemd` may drop some caps for some service, and if your binary with a full sets file capabilities will be ran by this service, only those caps which are in the bounding set of this service will be available in the process' effective set for your program, or even less).

Comment: I updated the question @DanilaKiver and added more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you write a program that wants to grant file capabilities to anything without also containing code that performs sanity checks or some form of authentication, you can. (Programmers can write code to do all sorts of things.)

In fact, `/sbin/setcap` is such a program:

```
$ cp /sbin/setcap ./easycap
$ chmod go-rwx ./easycap
$ sudo ./easycap cap_setfcap=p ./easycap
$ ./easycap =ep ./easycap
$ /sbin/getcap ./easycap
easycap =ep
```

Unlike `setuid-root` programs that can also do the same thing, here, the `chmod go-rwx ./easycap` restricts access to this powerful binary to just the `whoami` user.

To grant this program the `cap_setfcap` capability, the program has to get it from somewhere. In this case, the `sudo` user is granting this binary permission to give any file capability to any binary it can write to.

That is, it is the `sudo` invoker who thinks this whole arrangement is a good idea. Done this way, or on a single user system, this might be really handy for an admin that understands all the ways this could be abused. In other, more likely, situations this might not be such a great idea.